# Insert into the database only if the data exists in a database table? PHP/AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I currently have a page where a user can add their skills. This comprises of a textbox and slider to select their skill level, that is all working.

I have a database table `'skill_list'` which has a list of skills and when the user starts typing into the textbox appropriate skills are shown with jquery autocomplete. Though a user can still pretty much type whatever they want and then save this skill which is inserted into a different database table called `'skills'`.

I want to be able to insert the data within the textbox to the database table `'skills'` only if the text is exactly equal to a skill name within `'skill_list'` database table? Therefore a user shouldn't be able to save the skills they have added and possibly prompted with an error using AJAX.

VIEW

```
<form method="post" action="skills/add" id="container">  

<script>

$.fn.addSlide = function () {
return this.each(function () {
    var $this = $(this),
        $num = $('.slide').length++,
        $name = $('<input type="text" class="inputField" id="autoskill-' + $num + '" name="skill-' + $num + '" placeholder="What\'s your skill?"></div>'),
        $slide = $('<br><div class="slide" id="slider-' + $num + '"></div><br>'),
        $amt = $('<input name="amount-' + $num + '" id="amount-' + $num + '" class="inputField" readonly placeholder="Slide to select this skill level..."/><br>');
    $this.append($name).append($amt).append($slide);
    $('.inputField').autocomplete({
        source:'skills/auto', 
        minLength:2
    });
    console.log($('#autoskill'));
    $slide.slider({
        value: 0,
        min: 0,
        max: 5,
        step: 1,
        slide: function (event, ui) {
            $amt.val(ui.value); 
        }
    });
});
}

$('body').on('click', '.addNew', function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
$('#newFields').addSlide();
}); 

var count = 0;  

$(document).ready(function(){   

$('.addNew').click( function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#length').html(count);       
    count++;
});

$('.submitButton').click( function(event){
    $('#container').append('<input type="hidden" name="count" value="' + count + '">');
});

});



</script>

<button class="addNew submitButton"> Add a Skill </button><br>

<div id="newFields"></div>

<input type="submit" class="submitButton" value="Save Skills">

</form>
```

CONTROLLER

```
public function auto(){

    $skill = $_GET['term'];

    $query = $this->db->query('SELECT * from skill_list WHERE name LIKE "%'.$skill.'%" ORDER by name ASC LIMIT 10');

    $data = array();

    if ( $query && $query->num_rows() ){

        foreach ($query->result_array() as $row){

            $data[$row['id']]=$row['name'];     

        }

    }

    echo json_encode($data);
    flush();

}

public function add(){

    $this->load->view('header');

    $id = $this->session->userdata('id');

    $skill_points = 0;

    for ($i = 0; $i < $_POST['count']; $i++) {

        $skill = $_POST['skill-'.$i.''];
        $level = $_POST['amount-'.$i.''];
        $points = $_POST['amount-'.$i.''] + 1;

        $query = $this->db->get_where('jobseeker_profiles', array('jobseeker_id' => $id));
        $user = $query->row_array();

        $this->db->set('jobseeker_profile_id', $user['id']);
        $this->db->set('name', $skill);
        $this->db->set('level', $level);
        $this->db->set('points_value', $points);

        $this->db->insert('skills');

        $skill_points += $points;
    }

    $this->db->set('skills_value', $skill_points);
    $this->db->where('jobseeker_id', $id);
    $this->db->update('jobseeker_profiles');

    $query = $this->db->get_where('jobseeker_profiles', array('jobseeker_id' => $id));
    $user = $query->row_array();

    $skills = $user['skills_value'];
    $qualifications = $user['qualifications_value'];
    $work_history = $user['work_history_value'];

    $total = $skills + $qualifications + $work_history;

    $this->db->set('total_points_value', $total);
    $this->db->where('jobseeker_id', $id);      
    $this->db->update('jobseeker_profiles');

    $this->db->set('points_value', $total);
    $this->db->where('jobseeker_profile_id', $user['id']);
    $this->db->update('applications');

    redirect('skills');

}
```

Thanks

Comment: If you're not going to let them enter their own skill unless it exactly matches a pre-defined skill, give them a dropdown menu in which to choose a skill. Otherwise you'll confuse and frustrate the user. Or am I completely misreading your question?

Comment: @Tim Well I would but the database table 'skill_list' will contain hundreds if not thousands of different skills once fully populated. I also understand where you are coming from though. I've seen some websites have like a green border if correct and red if it doesn't exist, how would you do something like this?

Comment: OK, I'm understanding where you're coming from now. How are you planning on getting all of those skills into the database in the first place? Are the users going to enter them? If so, they won't be able to enter *any* skills with that check in place. I've run into this problem a couple times: in one instance i just used a typeahead and forced them to choose a match, and in the other (user-contributable) I slugged the items to keep duplicates to a minimum. Not sure if that helps though...

Comment: Well at the moment I'm just entering them into a csv and uploading to the 'skill_list' table. I think I might use typeahead solution. Am I right in thinking that typeahead is the exact same as autocomplete or is there differences?

Comment: it's the same thing, just a different name. it's a good solution that shouldn't frustrate your visitors. it's important to maintain relatively strict control of your data, even if it's community-driven or you'll get *lots* of duplicates - as you've already thought of. I learned this the hard way. :)

Comment: I see. In this circumstance, will a user still be able to save even if the text they type in doesn't exist in the 'skill_list' database table?

Comment: That's up to you. If you allow it, just make sure you're aggressively checking against dups.